# Adding listview items

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview, items

I have some doubts in listveiw
I have a listview with two columns, i want to add items to the first column which are given programmatically and the other column is from database... like

```
column1              column2

apple            from database
orange                "
banana                "
```

can this be done....
can any one help me out with this...

I am using C# ,visual studio..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you want to match the programmatically added values and the db values, but you could create a new listitem for each of the database values i.e.

```
ListItem item = new ListItem("apple",[database value]);
```

Add the items to a collection

```
ItemCollection.Items.Add(item);
```

Then bind the collection to your control

```
ListView.DataSource = ItemCollection;
```